# Regex JS: Matching string between two strings including newlines

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match string between two string with Regex including newlines.

For example, I have the next string:

```
{count, plural,
  one {apple}
  other {apples}
}
```

I need to get string between `plural,` and `one`. It will be `\n*space**space*`.
I tried this Regex:

```
/(?:plural,)(.*?)(?:one)/gs
```

It works, but not in JS. How to do that with JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match the everything including newline character, you can use `[\s\S]` or `[^]`

```js
var str = `{count, plural,
  one {apple}
  other {apples}
} `;
console.log(str.match(/(?:plural,)([\s\S]*?)(?:one)/g));
console.log(str.match(/(?:plural,)([^]*?)(?:one)/g));
```

Comment: `m` here is redundant.

Comment: Yes, `m` is redundant Thanks for pointing out. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Simply because `m` affects mean of `^` / `$` anchors to be start / end of subject string (default behavior) or start / end of line. I think what you are referring to as multi-line is dotall `s` flag which enables `.` to accept newline characters as well. Being not supported, `s` will be shipped with ES2018, hopefully.

Comment: Thanks @revo for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn´t work because your testing with the wrong regex engine.

```
 `/s` does not exist in the JS regex engine, only in pcre
```

It must be something like:

```
/(?:plural,)((.|\n)*?)(?:one)/g
```

Hope it helps.