# Regex between two specific patterns including newline

Tags: r, regex, text

I have a text file with the following pattern:

```
Prof. Imperdiet montes, metus elementum eleifend eget eget adipiscing augue.
Abstract title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing

A, nec, quam eleifend quis, magnis sit pretium. leo augue. amet, elit. vel
Vel, dis eget nascetur justo. imperdiet consequat et sit Nam Aenean a, Quisque
Enim. a, dui. Aenean lorem Phasellus commodo quis, pretium ultricies nascetur
tincidunt. sem. vitae,
montes, tellus. amet, venenatis natoque enim. fringilla
quis, vitae, Aenean Etiam viverra ipsum dapibus ut elementum Aenean Lorem eget,
nisi mollis Curabitur Quisque Aenean rhoncus sociis justo, sem. justo, vel
Aenean ultricies nec, eu laoreet.

Dr. Enim. vitae, feugiat in, Aenean
Abstract title: Massa. sociis dis dapibus dolor semper ipsum
jalor

Semper tincidunt. ullamcorper commodo magnis viverra pede elit. eget aliquet
eleifend vel, eleifend feugiat pede Vivamus ridiculus vitae, a, ligula, et Nulla
ligula vulputate ac, nisi. enim dapibus. Donec metus In sit dolor Nam ultricies
imperdiet. pellentesque Cras eu, massa quis porttitor parturient varius ut,
Phasellus arcu. pretium. quam augue. eu, adipiscing felis, enim. ante,
vulputate Integer dui. ultricies a, dictum rutrum. Nullam nec, quis,
consequat Cum tellus. dis felis dolor. nulla Aliquam Donec massa. justo. in,
nascetur
Semper tincidunt. ullamcorper commodo magnis viverra pede elit. eget aliquet
eleifend vel, eleifend feugiat pede Vivamus ridiculus vitae, a, ligula, et Nulla


Dr. Justo. nisi elementum ante, Donec Aenean Nulla
Abstract title:

Aenean consectetuer leo penatibus eget imperdiet nisi. consequat
lorem pretium mus. 

Prof. Dr. Aliquam metus semper
Abstract title: Aliquet augue. amet, enim ut justo, nec, eleifend lorem enim. nisi. ipsum
eleifend
More information will be available soon.
```

I want to extract these parts:

> Abstract title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing

> Abstract title: Massa. sociis dis dapibus dolor semper ipsum
> jalor

> Abstract title:

and

> Abstract title: Aliquet augue. amet, enim ut justo, nec, eleifend lorem enim. nisi. ipsum
> eleifend
> More information will be available soon.

Now, I found these are helpful:

- [Regex JS: Matching string between two strings including newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739859/regex-js-matching-string-between-two-strings-including-newlines)
- [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454936/9592557)

but `(?<=(Abstract title:))(.*)(?=\n{2})` returns only

> Abstract title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing

and

> Abstract title:

Also I am not sure what software tool would be most efficient – [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) , [r](/questions/tagged/r)? Please forgive if it's noob question but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Try something like `(?s)(?<=Abstract title:).*?(?=\n{2})`. Or `(?<=Abstract title:).*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lbBTWZ/1). Are you using it with `stringr` in R?

Comment: What tool do you use for the extraction? Different tools support different flavours of regex.

Comment: If you are using JS, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work - possibly you are looking for multiline modification

Comment: Have u ever checked my answer?

Comment: A small but important correction in the MWO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you can extract your matches and "normalize" all whitespace inside matches to a regular single space using

```r
x <- "Prof. Imperdiet montes, metus elementum eleifend eget eget adipiscing augue.\nAbstract title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing\n\nA, nec, quam eleifend quis, magnis sit pretium. leo augue. amet, elit. vel\n\nVel, dis eget nascetur justo. imperdiet consequat et sit Nam Aenean a, Quisque\nEnim. a, dui. Aenean lorem Phasellus commodo quis, pretium ultricies nascetur\ntincidunt. sem. vitae,\nmontes, tellus. amet, venenatis natoque enim. fringilla\nquis, vitae, Aenean Etiam viverra ipsum dapibus ut elementum Aenean Lorem eget,\nnisi mollis Curabitur Quisque Aenean rhoncus sociis justo, sem. justo, vel\nAenean ultricies nec, eu laoreet.\n\nDr. Enim. vitae, feugiat in, Aenean\nAbstract title: Massa. sociis dis dapibus dolor semper ipsum\njalor\n\nSemper tincidunt. ullamcorper commodo magnis viverra pede elit. eget aliquet\neleifend vel, eleifend feugiat pede Vivamus ridiculus vitae, a, ligula, et Nulla\nligula vulputate ac, nisi. enim dapibus. Donec metus In sit dolor Nam ultricies\nimperdiet. pellentesque Cras eu, massa quis porttitor parturient varius ut,\nPhasellus arcu. pretium. quam augue. eu, adipiscing felis, enim. ante,\nvulputate Integer dui. ultricies a, dictum rutrum. Nullam nec, quis,\nconsequat Cum tellus. dis felis dolor. nulla Aliquam Donec massa. justo. in,\nnascetur\nSemper tincidunt. ullamcorper commodo magnis viverra pede elit. eget aliquet\neleifend vel, eleifend feugiat pede Vivamus ridiculus vitae, a, ligula, et Nulla\n\n\nDr. Justo. nisi elementum ante, Donec Aenean Nulla\nAbstract title:\n\nAenean consectetuer leo penatibus eget imperdiet nisi. consequat\nlorem pretium mus. \n\nProf. Dr. Aliquam metus semper\nAbstract title: Aliquet augue. amet, enim ut justo, nec, eleifend lorem enim. nisi. ipsum\neleifend\nMore information will be available soon.\n"
library(stringr)
pattern <- "(?<=Abstract title:).*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*"
results <- lapply(str_extract_all(x, pattern), function(z) trimws(gsub("\\s+", " ", z)))
```

The `results` will look like

```
[[1]]
[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing"                                                                        
[2] "Massa. sociis dis dapibus dolor semper ipsum jalor"                                                                         
[3] ""                                                                                                                           
[4] "Aliquet augue. amet, enim ut justo, nec, eleifend lorem enim. nisi. ipsum eleifend More information will be available soon."
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/ODC5M5) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lbBTWZ/1).

*Regex details*:

- `(?<=Abstract title:)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a position that is immediately preceded with `Abstract title:`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:\n(?!\n).*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\n(?!\n)` - a line feed char not immediately followed with another line feed char
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible

The `lapply(..., function(z) trimws(gsub("\\s+", " ", z)))` "shrinks" the whitespace in the resulting list.

**Parsing the text file into two columns**

You can use

```r
library(readr)
library(stringr)
file <- read_lines(path)
file_string <- paste(file, collapse="\n")
pattern <- "(?m)^(.+)\n(Abstract title:.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)"
res <- str_match_all(file_string, pattern)
res <- lapply(res, function(z) trimws(gsub("\\s+", " ", z[,-1])))
```

The output is

```
[[1]]
     [,1]                                                                           [,2]                                                                                                                                         
[1,] "Prof. Imperdiet montes, metus elementum eleifend eget eget adipiscing augue." "Abstract title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing"                                                                        
[2,] "Dr. Enim. vitae, feugiat in, Aenean"                                          "Abstract title: Massa. sociis dis dapibus dolor semper ipsum jalor"                                                                         
[3,] "Dr. Justo. nisi elementum ante, Donec Aenean Nulla"                           "Abstract title:"                                                                                                                            
[4,] "Prof. Dr. Aliquam metus semper"                                               "Abstract title: Aliquet augue. amet, enim ut justo, nec, eleifend lorem enim. nisi. ipsum eleifend More information will be available soon."
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237605/discussion-between-massisenergy-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex,

`Abstract title:(?:.|\r?\n\w)*`

It captures everything like:

- Abstract title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
- Abstract title: Massa. sociis dis dapibus dolor semper ipsum jalor
- Abstract title:
- Abstract title: Aliquet augue. amet, enim ut justo, nec, eleifend lorem enim. nisi. ipsum eleifend More information will be available soon.

(As you mentioned in your question)

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/VrW49j/1)

tell me if its okay for you...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sorry for the late reply as I am not as fast as most of you here XD.
As you can see from the discussion in
[In R, you can extract your matches and "normalize" all whitespace inside matches to a regular single space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69363652/9592557),
I actually posted only part of the problem otherwise it would have been too
complicated IMO. So, here I put the pieces together. Whomever commented or
answered, has been helpful. I accept the answer as he spent a lot of time & guided me to the right direction.

**GOAL**
Please take a look at the MWO in the question, for reference. I need to extract
three individual columns from a text file, which was extracted using `pdftotext`
on a `pdf` with texts and images. The end result should be a data frame with three columns. The three columns will be, for example

Column 1.

> Dr. Enim. vitae, feugiat in, Aenean

Column 2.

> Abstract title: Massa. sociis dis dapibus dolor semper ipsum jalor

Column 3.

> Semper tincidunt. ullamcorper ... viverra pede elit. eget aliquet
> eleifend vel, eleifend feugiat pede Vivamus ridiculus vitae, a, ligula, et Nulla

So, the newlines need to be kept intact which [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) and I realised.
So, it's hard to do with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). I took cue from
[Wiktor Stribiżew's answer with r](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69363652/9592557).

### read the pattern such as the one provided in the question

**Reading the pattern & removing of carriage return `\f` or `U+000C`**

```
wholeFileAsString <- read_file(file="pattern.txt")

wholeFileAsString <- wholeFileAsString %>% str_remove("\f");
testString <- "Prof. Imperdiet montes, metus elementum eleifend eget eget adipiscing augue.
Abstract title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing

A, nec, quam eleifend quis, magnis sit pretium. leo augue. amet, elit. vel
Vel, dis eget nascetur justo. imperdiet consequat et sit Nam Aenean a, Quisque
Enim. a, dui. Aenean lorem Phasellus commodo quis, pretium ultricies nascetur
tincidunt. sem. vitae,
montes, tellus. amet, venenatis natoque enim. fringilla
quis, vitae, Aenean Etiam viverra ipsum dapibus ut elementum Aenean Lorem eget,
nisi mollis Curabitur Quisque Aenean rhoncus sociis justo, sem. justo, vel
Aenean ultricies nec, eu laoreet.

Dr. Enim. vitae, feugiat in, Aenean
Abstract title: Massa. sociis dis dapibus dolor semper ipsum
jalor

Semper tincidunt. ullamcorper commodo magnis viverra pede elit. eget aliquet
eleifend vel, eleifend feugiat pede Vivamus ridiculus vitae, a, ligula, et Nulla
ligula vulputate ac, nisi. enim dapibus. Donec metus In sit dolor Nam ultricies
imperdiet. pellentesque Cras eu, massa quis porttitor parturient varius ut,
Phasellus arcu. pretium. quam augue. eu, adipiscing felis, enim. ante,
vulputate Integer dui. ultricies a, dictum rutrum. Nullam nec, quis,
consequat Cum tellus. dis felis dolor. nulla Aliquam Donec massa. justo. in,
nascetur
Semper tincidunt. ullamcorper commodo magnis viverra pede elit. eget aliquet
eleifend vel, eleifend feugiat pede Vivamus ridiculus vitae, a, ligula, et Nulla


Dr. Justo. nisi elementum ante, Donec Aenean Nulla
Abstract title:

Aenean consectetuer leo penatibus eget imperdiet nisi. consequat
lorem pretium mus. 

Prof. Dr. Aliquam metus semper
Abstract title: Aliquet augue. amet, enim ut justo, nec, eleifend lorem enim. nisi. ipsum
eleifend
More information will be available soon."
```

### Extracting the `AbstractTitle` and `Name` columns individually.

```
pattern_AbstractTitle <- "(?m)(^Abstract.*\n){1}(.*\n)";
pattern_AbstractTitle <- "(?m)(^Abstract.*\n){1}^((?!More).)*";
AbstractTitle <- str_extract_all(wholeFileAsString, pattern_AbstractTitle) %>% 
    unlist() %>% as.vector();
pattern_Name <- "(?m)(?<=\n\n)\f?(?:^.*\n)(.*\n)?(?=^Ab(s?)tract.*)";
Name <- wholeFileAsString %>% str_extract_all(pattern_Name) %>% unlist() %>% 
    as.vector() %>% c("Prof. Mauro Alini, AO Research Institute", .);
AbstractTitle <- append(AbstractTitle, 
    "Abstract title: more information will follow soon\n", after=
    length(AbstractTitle));
```

### Extracting the rest ( without the `AbstractTitle` and `Name` lines only).

```
pattern_NameAbstractTitle <- 
"(?m)(?<=\n\n)\f?(?:^.*\n)(.*\n)?(?=^Ab(s?)tract.*)(^Abstract.*\n){1}^((?!More).)*"
wholeFileAsString_wo_NameAbstractTitle <- wholeFileAsString %>% 
    str_remove_all(pattern_NameAbstractTitle) %>% as.vector();
```

### Writing the whole string into a `.txt`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21481387/9592557

```
# write.table(wholeFileAsString_wo_NameAbstractTitle, file = "outfile.txt")
writeLines(wholeFileAsString_wo_NameAbstractTitle, 
           "wholeFileAsString_wo_NameAbstractTitle.txt")
```

### Preparing the columns with short biography

```
# read_file(file = "wholeFileAsString_wo_NameAbstractTitle.txt")
wholeFileAsString_wo_NameAbstractTitle %>% str()
shortBio <- wholeFileAsString_wo_NameAbstractTitle %>% str_remove_all("\f") %>% 
    str_replace_all("(?m)\n(?!\n)","")
shortBio2 <- shortBio %>% str_replace_all("(?m)\n+","\n") %>% 
    str_extract_all(".*\n") %>% unlist(); str(shortBio); shortBio2; 
shortBio3 <- shortBio2 %>% as.vector(); shortBio3 <-
    shortBio3[2:length(shortBio3)];
shortBio4 <- shortBio3[-1]
```

### Writing the character strings into `.txt` files.

```
shortBio4 %>% writeLines("shortBio4.txt");
```

### Joining into a three-columned dataframe

```
dfNameAbstractTitle <- data.frame(Name, AbstractTitle);
dfNameAbstractTitle <- dfNameAbstractTitle %>% rbind(c(NA, NA));
dfNameAbstractTitleShortBio <- dfNameAbstractTitle %>% data.frame(shortBio4)
```